# Angular Material how to override .mat-form-field-hide-placeholder behavior with css

Tags: angular, angular-material

With Angular Material, I'm having trouble to css override the .mat-form-field-hide-placeholder class that is automatically added to the  parent mat-form-field tag when the input is out of focus. The goal is to always show the placeholder.

The code looks something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>
      Field label
  </mat-label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder text">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it working doing this:

Using SASS:

```
.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-hide-placeholder {
  .mat-form-field-infix {
    .mat-input-element::placeholder {
      color: $gray-350 !important;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: $gray-350 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Or plain CSS:

```
.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-hide-placeholder .mat-form-field-infix  .mat-input-element::placeholder {
      color: $gray-350 !important;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: $gray-350 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use /deep/ selector to properly override the class. This is a known problem in angular material.

```
/deep/ .mat-form-field-hide-placeholder {
    // your code here
}
```

It's important to know that /deep/ selector is currently being deprecated, but as far as I know currently doesn't have any alternative solution to this problem. So pay attention to future changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `appearance="fill"`.

In my case it's working well.

```html
<mat-form-field class="custom-chip-list" appearance="fill">
```

And if you used `mat-label`, please make sure, title is not emtpy or `null`.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFaUe.png)